# Mobius transformations — $L^{-1} \times M\lbrace0,1,\infty\rbrace\times L$

Tags: group-theory, transformation

$$L^{-1} \times M\lbrace0,1,\infty\rbrace\times L$$

I cannot seem to get the right answer when I multiple them out.

$$(1-i)z \cdot (1-z) \cdot \frac{z}{1-i}$$

What do you get when you multiple these out?

Comment: Usually, when Möbius transformations are multiplied, the functions themselves aren't multiplied, they're inserted into each other.

Comment: Please can you use this as an example

Comment: If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are Möbius transformations, then the composition of the two isn't $f(z)g(z)$, but $f(g(z))$.

Comment: I still dont completely understand could you finish this example as I have another 5 to do

Comment: I have managed to work it out by inserting them, i didnt no this is what you did rather than multiplying thank you